# How do I send an attachment with php mail

Tags: php

I have already exported a xls file but i want to mail this xls file in an attachment of the mail.

exportexcel.php

```
<?php
session_start();


//export format
$fileNamed = $username."_".$date_time; 
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel"); 
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileNamed.xls" ); 
header ("Content-Description: PHP/INTERBASE Generated Data" );

echo $data;
?>
```

the above php file exports in xls what ever is in $data. But i want to mail this xls file in a mail with attached xls file.

Answer (score 0):

An email can be split into many parts separated by a boundary followed by a Content-Type and a Content-Disposition.

The boundary is initialized as follows:

```
<?php
$boundary = '-----=' . md5( uniqid ( rand() ) );
?>
```

You can attach a Word document if you specify:

```
<?php
$message .= "Content-Type: application/msword; name=\"my attachment\"\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$theFile\"\n\n";
?>
```

When adding a file you must open it and read it with fopen and add the content to the message:

```
<?php
$path = "whatever the path to the file is";
$fp = fopen($path, 'r');
do //we loop until there is no data left
{
        $data = fread($fp, 8192);
        if (strlen($data) == 0) break;
        $content .= $data;
      } while (true);
$content_encode = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$message .= $content_encode . "\n";
$message .= "--" . $boundary . "\n";
?>
```

Add the needed headers and send!

```
<?php
$headers  = "From: \"Me\"<me@example.com>\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"";
mail('myAddress@example.com', 'Email with attachment from PHP', $message, $headers);
```